# Corosync/Pacemaker/DRBD Resilience Tuning

Tags: cluster, pacemaker, drbd, corosync

I have a DRBD cluster and one node was switched off for a couple of days. The single node ran fine without a hiccup. When i switch it on I got into a situation where all resources got stopped and one DRBD volume was secondary and the others primary as it seemingly tried to perform a role swap to the node just switched on (ha1 was live and then i switched on ha2 at 08:06 for the sake of logs understanding)

My questions:

- can anyone help me figure out what happened here ? (I'd be willing to consider paid consulting to get the configuration right if this question is deemed too laborious).
- as a side question, if a situation resolved itself, is there a way to have pcs do a resource cleanup by itself ? LinuxHA clusters did not require intervention if a fault condition cleared after fail-over so I'm either spoiled or ignorant of how to achieve this.

Below all potentially useful information i could imagine one might ask for.

```
bash-5.1# cat /proc/drbd 
version: 8.4.11 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 60F610B702CC05315B04B50 
 0: cs:Connected ro:Secondary/Primary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:109798092 nr:90528 dw:373317496 dr:353811713 al:558387 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
 1: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:415010252 nr:188601628 dw:1396698240 dr:1032339078 al:1387347 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
 2: cs:Connected ro:Primary/Secondary ds:UpToDate/UpToDate C r-----
    ns:27957772 nr:21354732 dw:97210572 dr:100798651 al:5283 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:0
```

The cluster state ended up as

```
bash-5.1# pcs status
Cluster name: HA
Status of pacemakerd: 'Pacemaker is running' (last updated 2023-08-10 08:38:40Z)
Cluster Summary:
  * Stack: corosync
  * Current DC: ha2.local (version 2.1.4-5.el9_1.2-dc6eb4362e) - partition with quorum
  * Last updated: Thu Aug 10 08:38:40 2023
  * Last change:  Mon Jul 10 06:49:08 2023 by hacluster via crmd on ha1.local
  * 2 nodes configured
  * 14 resource instances configured

Node List:
  * Online: [ ha1.local ha2.local ]

Full List of Resources:
  * Clone Set: LV_BLOB-clone [LV_BLOB] (promotable):
    * Promoted: [ ha2.local ]
    * Unpromoted: [ ha1.local ]
  * Resource Group: nsdrbd:
    * LV_BLOBFS (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem):  Started ha2.local
    * LV_POSTGRESFS (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem):  Stopped
    * LV_HOMEFS (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem):  Stopped
    * ClusterIP (ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2):     Stopped
  * Clone Set: LV_POSTGRES-clone [LV_POSTGRES] (promotable):
    * Promoted: [ ha1.local ]
    * Unpromoted: [ ha2.local ]
  * postgresql  (systemd:postgresql):    Stopped
  * Clone Set: LV_HOME-clone [LV_HOME] (promotable):
    * Promoted: [ ha1.local ]
    * Unpromoted: [ ha2.local ]
  * ns_mhswdog  (lsb:mhswdog):   Stopped
  * Clone Set: pingd-clone [pingd]:
    * Started: [ ha1.local ha2.local ]

Failed Resource Actions:
  * LV_POSTGRES promote on ha2.local could not be executed (Timed Out: Resource agent did not complete within 1m30s) at Thu Aug 10 08:19:27 2023 after 1m30.003s
  * LV_BLOB promote on ha2.local could not be executed (Timed Out: Resource agent did not complete within 1m30s) at Thu Aug 10 08:15:38 2023 after 1m30.001s

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

I attach the logs of the two nodes

```
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 2 link: 0 is up
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] pmtud: Global data MTU changed to: 1397
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync members[2]: 1 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync joined[1]: 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (1.12d) was formed. Members joined: 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Members[2]: 1 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1032387] ha1.local corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Aug 10 08:07:07 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 2 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:07:07 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:11:48 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] link: host: 2 link: 1 is down
Aug 10 08:11:48 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:11:50 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 2 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:11:50 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:12:22 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] link: host: 2 link: 1 is down
Aug 10 08:12:22 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:12:23 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 2 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:12:23 [1032387] ha1.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 2 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
```

and

```
Aug 10 08:06:55 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Corosync Cluster Engine 3.1.5 starting up
Aug 10 08:06:55 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [MAIN  ] Corosync built-in features: dbus systemd xmlconf vqsim nozzle snmp pie relro bindnow
Aug 10 08:06:56 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [TOTEM ] Initializing transport (Kronosnet).
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [TOTEM ] totemknet initialized
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] common: crypto_nss.so has been loaded from /usr/lib64/kronosnet/crypto_nss.so
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync configuration map access [0]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [QB    ] server name: cmap
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync configuration service [1]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [QB    ] server name: cfg
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync cluster closed process group service v1.01 [2]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [QB    ] server name: cpg
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync profile loading service [4]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Using quorum provider corosync_votequorum
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync vote quorum service v1.0 [5]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [QB    ] server name: votequorum
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [SERV  ] Service engine loaded: corosync cluster quorum service v0.1 [3]
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [QB    ] server name: quorum
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [TOTEM ] Configuring link 0
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [TOTEM ] Configured link number 0: local addr: 192.168.51.216, port=5405
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [TOTEM ] Configuring link 1
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [TOTEM ] Configured link number 1: local addr: 10.0.0.2, port=5406
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync warning [KNET  ] host: host: 1 has no active links
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync members[1]: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync joined[1]: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (2.126) was formed. Members joined: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Members[1]: 2
Aug 10 08:06:57 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 1 link: 0 is up
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] pmtud: Global data MTU changed to: 469
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync members[2]: 1 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Sync joined[1]: 1
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [TOTEM ] A new membership (1.12d) was formed. Members joined: 1
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [VOTEQ ] Waiting for all cluster members. Current votes: 1 expected_votes: 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] This node is within the primary component and will provide service.
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [QUORUM] Members[2]: 1 2
Aug 10 08:07:00 [1128] ha2.local corosync notice  [MAIN  ] Completed service synchronization, ready to provide service.
Aug 10 08:07:05 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 1 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:07:05 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:07:08 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] pmtud: PMTUD link change for host: 1 link: 0 from 469 to 1397
Aug 10 08:07:08 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] pmtud: PMTUD link change for host: 1 link: 1 from 469 to 8885
Aug 10 08:07:08 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] pmtud: Global data MTU changed to: 1397
Aug 10 08:14:13 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] link: host: 1 link: 1 is down
Aug 10 08:14:13 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:14:15 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 1 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:14:15 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:19:53 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] link: host: 1 link: 1 is down
Aug 10 08:19:53 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:19:54 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 1 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:19:54 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:23:18 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] link: host: 1 link: 1 is down
Aug 10 08:23:18 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
Aug 10 08:23:19 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] rx: host: 1 link: 1 is up
Aug 10 08:23:19 [1128] ha2.local corosync info    [KNET  ] host: host: 1 (passive) best link: 0 (pri: 1)
```

I also attach the output of pcs config show and can also provide pcs cluster cib on request

```
Cluster Name: HA
Corosync Nodes:
 ha1.local ha2.local
Pacemaker Nodes:
 ha1.local ha2.local

Resources:
  Resource: postgresql (class=systemd type=postgresql)
    Operations:
      monitor: postgresql-monitor-interval-60s
        interval=60s
      start: postgresql-start-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=100
      stop: postgresql-stop-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=100
  Resource: ns_mhswdog (class=lsb type=mhswdog)
    Operations:
      force-reload: ns_mhswdog-force-reload-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=15
      monitor: ns_mhswdog-monitor-interval-60s
        interval=60s
        timeout=10s
        on-fail=standby
      restart: ns_mhswdog-restart-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=140s
      start: ns_mhswdog-start-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=80s
      stop: ns_mhswdog-stop-interval-0s
        interval=0s
        timeout=80s
  Group: nsdrbd
    Resource: LV_BLOBFS (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
      Attributes: LV_BLOBFS-instance_attributes
        device=/dev/drbd0
        directory=/data
        fstype=ext4
      Operations:
        monitor: LV_BLOBFS-monitor-interval-20s
          interval=20s
          timeout=40s
        start: LV_BLOBFS-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
        stop: LV_BLOBFS-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
    Resource: LV_POSTGRESFS (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
      Attributes: LV_POSTGRESFS-instance_attributes
        device=/dev/drbd1
        directory=/var/lib/pgsql
        fstype=ext4
      Operations:
        monitor: LV_POSTGRESFS-monitor-interval-20s
          interval=20s
          timeout=40s
        start: LV_POSTGRESFS-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
        stop: LV_POSTGRESFS-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
    Resource: LV_HOMEFS (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
      Attributes: LV_HOMEFS-instance_attributes
        device=/dev/drbd2
        directory=/home
        fstype=ext4
      Operations:
        monitor: LV_HOMEFS-monitor-interval-20s
          interval=20s
          timeout=40s
        start: LV_HOMEFS-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
        stop: LV_HOMEFS-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
    Resource: ClusterIP (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=IPaddr2)
      Attributes: ClusterIP-instance_attributes
        cidr_netmask=32
        ip=192.168.51.75
      Operations:
        monitor: ClusterIP-monitor-interval-60s
          interval=60s
        start: ClusterIP-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=20s
        stop: ClusterIP-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=20s
  Clone: LV_BLOB-clone
    Meta Attributes: LV_BLOB-clone-meta_attributes
      clone-max=2
      clone-node-max=1
      notify=true
      promotable=true
      promoted-max=1
      promoted-node-max=1
    Resource: LV_BLOB (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
      Attributes: LV_BLOB-instance_attributes
        drbd_resource=lv_blob
      Operations:
        demote: LV_BLOB-demote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        monitor: LV_BLOB-monitor-interval-60s
          interval=60s
          role=Promoted
        monitor: LV_BLOB-monitor-interval-63s
          interval=63s
          role=Unpromoted
        notify: LV_BLOB-notify-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        promote: LV_BLOB-promote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        reload: LV_BLOB-reload-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=30
        start: LV_BLOB-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=240
        stop: LV_BLOB-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=100
  Clone: LV_POSTGRES-clone
    Meta Attributes: LV_POSTGRES-clone-meta_attributes
      clone-max=2
      clone-node-max=1
      notify=true
      promotable=true
      promoted-max=1
      promoted-node-max=1
    Resource: LV_POSTGRES (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
      Attributes: LV_POSTGRES-instance_attributes
        drbd_resource=lv_postgres
      Operations:
        demote: LV_POSTGRES-demote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        monitor: LV_POSTGRES-monitor-interval-60s
          interval=60s
          role=Promoted
        monitor: LV_POSTGRES-monitor-interval-63s
          interval=63s
          role=Unpromoted
        notify: LV_POSTGRES-notify-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        promote: LV_POSTGRES-promote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        reload: LV_POSTGRES-reload-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=30
        start: LV_POSTGRES-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=240
        stop: LV_POSTGRES-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=100
  Clone: LV_HOME-clone
    Meta Attributes: LV_HOME-clone-meta_attributes
      clone-max=2
      clone-node-max=1
      notify=true
      promotable=true
      promoted-max=1
      promoted-node-max=1
    Resource: LV_HOME (class=ocf provider=linbit type=drbd)
      Attributes: LV_HOME-instance_attributes
        drbd_resource=lv_home
      Operations:
        demote: LV_HOME-demote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        monitor: LV_HOME-monitor-interval-60s
          interval=60s
          role=Promoted
        monitor: LV_HOME-monitor-interval-63s
          interval=63s
          role=Unpromoted
        notify: LV_HOME-notify-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        promote: LV_HOME-promote-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=90
        reload: LV_HOME-reload-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=30
        start: LV_HOME-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=240
        stop: LV_HOME-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=100
  Clone: pingd-clone
    Resource: pingd (class=ocf provider=pacemaker type=ping)
      Attributes: pingd-instance_attributes
        dampen=6s
        host_list=192.168.51.251
        multiplier=1000
      Operations:
        monitor: pingd-monitor-interval-10s
          interval=10s
          timeout=60s
        reload-agent: pingd-reload-agent-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=20s
        start: pingd-start-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=60s
        stop: pingd-stop-interval-0s
          interval=0s
          timeout=20s

Stonith Devices:
Fencing Levels:

Location Constraints:
  Resource: ClusterIP
    Constraint: location-ClusterIP
      Rule: boolean-op=or score=-INFINITY (id:location-ClusterIP-rule)
        Expression: pingd lt 1 (id:location-ClusterIP-rule-expr)
        Expression: not_defined pingd (id:location-ClusterIP-rule-expr-1)
Ordering Constraints:
  promote LV_BLOB-clone then start LV_BLOBFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_BLOB-clone-LV_BLOBFS-mandatory)
  promote LV_POSTGRES-clone then start LV_POSTGRESFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_POSTGRES-clone-LV_POSTGRESFS-mandatory)
  start LV_POSTGRESFS then start postgresql (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_POSTGRESFS-postgresql-mandatory)
  promote LV_HOME-clone then start LV_HOMEFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_HOME-clone-LV_HOMEFS-mandatory)
  start LV_HOMEFS then start ns_mhswdog (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_HOMEFS-ns_mhswdog-mandatory)
  start LV_BLOBFS then start ns_mhswdog (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-LV_BLOBFS-ns_mhswdog-mandatory)
  start postgresql then start ns_mhswdog (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-postgresql-ns_mhswdog-mandatory)
  start ns_mhswdog then start ClusterIP (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-ns_mhswdog-ClusterIP-mandatory)
Colocation Constraints:
  LV_BLOBFS with LV_BLOB-clone (score:INFINITY) (with-rsc-role:Promoted) (id:colocation-LV_BLOBFS-LV_BLOB-clone-INFINITY)
  LV_POSTGRESFS with LV_POSTGRES-clone (score:INFINITY) (with-rsc-role:Promoted) (id:colocation-LV_POSTGRESFS-LV_POSTGRES-clone-INFINITY)
  postgresql with LV_POSTGRESFS (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-postgresql-LV_POSTGRESFS-INFINITY)
  LV_HOMEFS with LV_HOME-clone (score:INFINITY) (with-rsc-role:Promoted) (id:colocation-LV_HOMEFS-LV_HOME-clone-INFINITY)
  ns_mhswdog with LV_HOMEFS (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ns_mhswdog-LV_HOMEFS-INFINITY)
  ns_mhswdog with LV_BLOBFS (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ns_mhswdog-LV_BLOBFS-INFINITY)
  ns_mhswdog with postgresql (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ns_mhswdog-postgresql-INFINITY)
  ClusterIP with ns_mhswdog (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ClusterIP-ns_mhswdog-INFINITY)
Ticket Constraints:

Alerts:
 No alerts defined

Resources Defaults:
  Meta Attrs: build-resource-defaults
    resource-stickiness=INFINITY
Operations Defaults:
  Meta Attrs: op_defaults-meta_attributes
    timeout=240s

Cluster Properties:
 cluster-infrastructure: corosync
 cluster-name: HA
 dc-version: 2.1.4-5.el9_1.2-dc6eb4362e
 have-watchdog: false
 last-lrm-refresh: 1688971748
 maintenance-mode: false
 no-quorum-policy: ignore
 stonith-enabled: false

Tags:
 No tags defined

Quorum:
  Options:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clusters like Pacemaker are highly configurable, and try to be careful because they can yank block devices, your data, between nodes. Testing the behavior of your cluster in various situations is not optional. Ideally, this results in operational playbooks of what to do in various scenarios.

Read the manual. The downstream distros that support Pacemaker, like the [RHEL HA guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/), explain many scenarios and provide reference.

You can configure resources to [prefer the node they are currently running](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_determining-which-node-a-resource-runs-on-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters#proc_setting-resource-stickiness-determining-which-node-a-resource-runs-on). A non-zero value cluster wide is probably a good idea, as in

```
pcs resource defaults update resource-stickiness=1
```

A location constraint with a higher value then this can still move resources.

[Performing cluster maintenance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_and_managing_high_availability_clusters/assembly_cluster-maintenance-configuring-and-managing-high-availability-clusters) topic has a reference for moving, stopping and starting. Planned maintenance on a node should probably be wrapped in `pcs node standby`  then `pcs node unstandby`

Try a `pcs resource move`  to get your resource group on the same node. Watch what happens after the move constraint is gone. If resources move back and you didn't want that, troubleshoot stickiness, constraints, dependencies, and other rules.

DRDB status of up UpToDate implies your volumes are healthy. Move things around with the cluster tools, and confirm the volumes mount successfully.

Two node clusters are actually difficult. When they partition there is not a good way to select a primary. Consider adding another node for quorum purposes, even if it has no disks and cannot host this resource group.

Comment: I have resource-stickiness=INFINITY as default, is this worse than 1 ?

Comment: No, stickiness should mean it doesn't move. Implying that there is some other combination of rules moving things.

Answer (score 4):

It's a misconfigured fencing or quorum pick-up issue. It's a very typical DRBD behavior which works when it works but fails miserably with a split-brain or replicated volumes stuck in a wrong state at some point and for no real reason. I would recommend not to fix DRBD, as it's not fixable by design, but use your best chance to scrap it and use something more reliable out of the box. I'd really recommend Ceph due to its stability, outstanding performance, and huge community support.

Comment: I will not disagree that DRBD Split-brains can be painful, but they can be prevented with proper fencing configured. DRBD is not "broken by design".

Comment: @Stuka has a point actually. No storage solution negligent to data integrity could be called “mature”.  DRBD is still-born for sure.